# Delete files from DDMS using command prompt?

Tags: android, command-prompt, ddms

I'm trying to delete some files from DDMS `data/data/package_name/files/filename` How can i done this?

Comment: adb shell rm/yourpath/to/yourfilename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the File Explorer of the Eclipse DDMS plugin or the `adb shell` command from your android platform tools to browse and delete the file system on your device.

Comment: the command to remove files is `rm filename` if you want to delete directories use `rm -r directoryname`

Comment: WRONG: use `rmdir` to delete directories. `rm -r` recursively removes files and directories.

Answer (score 13):

`adb shell rm /yourpath/to/yourfilename`

Answer (score 4):

You can [use ADB to get into the device/emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) shell and then execute normal linux-commands.

In your case, you would use [`rm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm) to remove something (if you want to remove a folder use the `-r` parameter).

---

From the Android Docs:

> Internal Storage
>
> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, **files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.**

This might help you. You can also check if you can "delete application data" in Androids Application Manager.

Comment: What files are you trying to delete? I also found [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=757) which might also help you.

Comment: i just took contacts backup as a file (i don't know what format is this). I took this used by uri.getHost(). It's permission is -rw-rw---

Comment: So you want to delete the contact-backup?

Comment: yes, how can i change the permission. Is is possible to do this?